# Multi-thread @Scheduled Springboot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have an application running now using @scheduled and the threadPoolTaskScheduler.

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        return  taskScheduler;
    }

}
```

My task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void execute() {
         //do stuff
         //call a webservice
}
```

In the execute method I do some stuff and call a external webservice, this webservices have a limmitation, I cant use more than 10 threads per webservice call. And now I need to create another 3 methods like the execute (and make one external webservice call for for each of these "execute" methods).

So I have a total of 40 threads that I can use, but limited by 10 for each method.

I am wondering if there is some way to have one thread pool for each @scheduled method. Could you guys help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Which web service? Three more what? Why?

Comment: Sorry about that, I read again and realize that I was not clear at all. I change the question trying to explain better. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several pools if you want to but you should have to schedule the tasks manually according to what is answered in this question:

[Why does Spring 4 only allow one TaskScheduler in a context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758116/why-does-spring-4-only-allow-one-taskscheduler-in-a-context)

But, I don't understand why you need so many threads for calling a web service.

EDIT

After your clarification:

You create a bean with the call of a web service in a different thread:

```
@Bean 
public class WebServiceCaller {
    @Async
    public void callWebService() {
        //call your web service here
    }
}
```

In the caller class (It is important that is in another class for the autoproxy to work).

```
@Bean
public class Caller {
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceCaller caller;

    public void callWith10Threads() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            caller.callWebService();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to annotate your configuration with @EnableAsync.

What it is the key point here, is that they don't know how many threads you have in the pool or whatever, they only know how many requests you have sent (threads on their side). So call 10 times in a row with your different threads, and don't call 11 times. They will be fine.

Your configuration is your problem not theirs, and you can have your threadpool configured as you wish.

Comment: Clarifying the reason I need many threads to call this webservices:

Those webservices are from an external "partner" from my company and they are used to synchronize the data between 3 different systems. Each webservice can receive 100 "objects" to process per call (and took 1 minute to finish) and we are allowed to use 10 threads maximum per webservice. If we use more than 10 the partner system start refusing connections, if I use less threads it will take too long to process everything. 

That's the reason I need to control the maximum threads per webservice to call.

Thanks.